# FB.Api(/{post_id}) not returning all data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting for a user, and then I want to check the privacy setting for his post. My code is:

```js
function shareOnFacebookInit() {
 $('#share_on_fb').click(function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
     shareOnFacebookDialog();
    } else {
      FB.login(function(response) {
       if(response.authResponse) {
        shareOnFacebookDialog(); 
       } 
     }, {scope: ['publish_actions', 'read_stream']});
    }
  });
 });
}

function shareOnFacebookDialog() {
 FB.ui({
   method: 'share_open_graph',
   action_type: $('#facebook_namespace').data('namespace')+':book',
   action_properties: JSON.stringify({
       apartment: $("meta[property='og:url']").attr("content"),
   })
 }, function(response){
  if(response.error_code) {
   showNotification("Post was not shared! Please try again", "error");
  } else if(response.post_id) {
   FB.api('/'+respoonse.post_id,function(res) {
    console.log(res);
   });
  }
 });
}
```

According to the [Post api reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post?locale=he_IL) one of the returned fields should be "privacy". I'm getting a response with a some fields, but not privacy.

Any idea why this is?

Thanks! Uri

Comment: Ask for the privacy field. Just because a field exists doesn't mean it will be returned.

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly do I ask for it though?

Comment: You add fields=foo in the request if you want the foo field